# If a question is migrated to another Stack Exchange site, do you still keep the original rep on the original site?

Tags: discussion, migration, reputation

I asked a Lord of the Rings question and it was moved from Movies and TV to Sci-Fi.

I have earned rep from that question on Movies and TV but I also now earned rep on Sci-Fi for that question.

Will my original rep for the question on Movies and TV be kept or is it transfered to Sci-Fi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [this question and answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/do-migrated-questions-migrate-reputation-and-badges) at meta.StackOverflow says it all: reputation is moved to the other site.

I can confirm this. One of my answers here was migrated to physics and the rep went with it. I think this also applies to questions.

You should be able to see it in your reputation log when you tick the checkbox "show removed posts" at the bottom.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: So if a question I ask is moved to a site that I am not a member of, should I join that site?

Comment: @NiceOrc You don't have to, of course, but if you do, using your Stack Exchange account, your user card will be shown below the question and you will start with any rep you received on the question plus 100 bonus points.